# Setting form select disabled for a DOM element represented by a variable

Tags: jquery, variables, dom, select

I'm trying to make a form element, in this case the non-active options of a select input disabled. I came across this code here as a recommended solution:

```
$('#elementid option:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', true);
```

I'm using a variable to represent the object within my loop:

```
var sinput = $(this).parents("tr").find('select');
```

My question is - how do I apply the prop code via the representative variable sinput? Can I even do this?

Comment: Can you provide the complete example with the ``html``?

Comment: Hi Majed! Thanks for your willingness to help, I think I've sorted it now though!. Have a good day!

Comment: @MatthewGreenhalgh could you answer your own question for others that run across this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, the $(this) needs to be some object in an event

To re-use a var you can do

```
var $sinput = $(this).closest("tr").find('select');
$('option:not(:selected)', $sinput).prop('disabled', true);
```

or

```
var $sinput = $(this).closest("tr").find('select');
$sinput.find('option:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', true);
```

I would do it directly

```js
$(".dis").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest("tr")  // the row of the button
    .find('select option:not(:selected)') // all not selected options
    .prop('disabled', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button type="button" class="dis">Disable not selected</button>
      <select>
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2" selected>Two</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button type="button" class="dis">Disable not selected</button>
      <select>
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="1" selected>One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you just want to disable all not selected options in a table on page load, it could be

```
$(function() { 
 $("#tableId")
   .find('select option:not(:selected)')
   .prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: Thank you mplugjan! That works for me. Am I correct then in understanding that I can't apply access 'prop by using a variable which is equal to '  $(this).closest("tr") .find('select')'?

Comment: Yes you can, but that was not what was implied in your code. `$(this).parents("tr")` means you have a "this" in the first place. In my code it is a button. If you just want to disable all non-selected options on load it could be `$(function() {  $("#tableId").find('select option:not(:selected)')
    .prop('disabled', true); })`

Comment: Ah thankyou, in this case, it's generating dynamic rows. Your code works, and I've incorporated it. I suppose I was just wondering if it was possible to substitute the $(this) find function with a variable which was equal to what would be returned in the code. Sorry for any confusion. I'm doing my best to learn this all to a deadline :)

Comment: `$('option:not(:selected)', $sinput)` us using the variable as a scope

Comment: Having looked further, I believe that - sinput.find('option:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', true); will work also. Thanks for helping me find the answer! Have a super day friend :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this one can be achieved in two ways -

$('option:not(:selected)', $sinput);

sinput.find('option:not(:selected)');